# Categories admin K2 joomla by alphabet sort?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

I would like to know how i could sort my categories admin by alphabet automatically ?
Thx for your help ^^

Comment: What about overriding the layout ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a list of sub-categories that appear on a category page. If so, you can edit the parent category and change the "Sub-category ordering" to "Titles Alphabetical." This option is found under the "Category view options" tab.

Comment: I haven't sub categories but only categories :( IMaybe it could works with a little script...